# MySQL Update Set for multiple rows at once

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL via command line and `UPDATE database.table SET column = REPLACE (column, item1, item2);` repeatedly, where each query contains different data for "item1, item2". There would be about 20 different queries and I will be using that same exact set at least 3 times during some testing and other work and I am wondering if there is one query I can use i.e. how can I combine all 20 versions of this into one to save myself time?

For example, here are the separate queries I ran and am wondering if I could combine them into one query.

```
mysql> update quiz_node_results set nid = replace (nid, 184461, 5784);
Query OK, 2057 rows affected (0.22 sec)
Rows matched: 33650  Changed: 2057  Warnings: 0

mysql> update quiz_node_results set nid = replace (nid, 184457, 5785);
Query OK, 2891 rows affected (0.17 sec)
Rows matched: 33650  Changed: 2891  Warnings: 0

mysql> update quiz_node_results set nid = replace (nid, 184462, 5786);
Query OK, 2189 rows affected (0.31 sec)
Rows matched: 33650  Changed: 2189  Warnings: 0
```

Only imagine that there are 20 all together instead of just these 3.

Comment: can you explain bit more

Comment: I revised my question with an example.

Comment: Does `nid` field contain 1 number or does it contain a string of values?

Comment: Addition #1 to my answer: Is the last number (in your example 5784, 5785, 5786) always increased by exactly 1?

Comment: Addition #2 to my answer: If you don't want to take the text file approach, you could type the statements one after another without hitting return in between. The semicolon is a separator which finishes a statement; you can add the next statement directly after the semicolon. If you have several statements in one line and you hit ENTER, all statements will be executed in one batch, from left to right. The only limitation for that is the maximum length for the command line in MySQL client (which I don't know right now). That could be an easy way for making multiple statements one statement.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect and the fact that the second set of values increases by 1 is a coincidence, not a rule. I need to be able to perfectly control these so making a .txt file that I only have to double-check once and then modify if/as needed is the solution I was looking for. I edited my question title also to help clarify things.

Comment: Just in case you'd also like to try Sagar Gangwal's answer: It won't work then ...

Comment: I noticed and it's okay, I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely sure if I have understood what you want to do, but you could just write the set of statements into a plain text file and feed that text file to MySQL.

Text file (let's assume its name is test.sql):

```
update quiz_node_results set nid = replace (nid, 184461, 5784);
update quiz_node_results set nid = replace (nid, 184457, 5785);
...
```

Of course, in the text file, you would have to add the "prologue" commands (like selecting the right database and other stuff to initialize correctly (if you need it)).

Then, at the command line (not in the MySQL client, but on the Linux / Windows command line):

```
mysql -p < test.sql
```

Please let me know if I have understood what you would like to do ...

Comment: That's a good idea. I've never tried this before, but if it works, than that's fine for me, thanks!

Comment: @Downvoter Why the downvote? Please enlight us with your wisdom.

Comment: I didn't but I think it's because you answered what I was looking for even though it was different than than how I worded my question originally. But you also answered it in the comments #2 so I'm happy. :) Maybe they'll take it back.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop procedure doiterate;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE doiterate(p1 INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE VAR_ITEM1 INT DEFAULT 184457;
DECLARE VAR_ITEM2 INT DEFAULT 5784;
  label1: LOOP
    SET p1 = p1 + 1;
    IF p1 < 20 THEN 
        update quiz_node_results set nid = replace (nid, VAR_ITEM1, VAR_ITEM2);
        SET VAR_ITEM1 := VAR_ITEM1+1;
        SET VAR_ITEM2 := VAR_ITEM2+1;
        ITERATE label1; 
    END IF;
    LEAVE label1;
  END LOOP label1;
END;
```

You can simply create simple procedure,which iterate for 20 times and update value using `UPDATE QUERY`.

Note: Here I am assuming you have ordered record need to be update.

Comment: Thank you, this is very thorough and well executed, but any perceived patterns in the set here are coincidental so this wouldn't work for my purpose.

Comment: @Sagar Gangwal This won't work. Her example already shows the first number sequence being 184461, 184457, 184462, so increasing by one (as in your code) does not help.

Comment: @Binarus Yes i know that,but what ever his order is he can manage using incremental or decremental form..

Comment: @SagarGangwal As far as have understood the OP, the numbers are absolutely random. There is no rule and no order.

Comment: @Binarus Then also it's not good practice to execute 20 UPDATE statement individually.In that scenario simply create one procedure and in procedure wrote all 20 statement and just call that procedure once.

Comment: @SagarGangwal I believe that my proposed solution (that one from my answer, not that one in my comments to the original question) is much easier, yet at least as clean as an SP. I think that many people do not have the development tools for editing SPs in a convenient way, and most people are not familiar with the concept of SPs. Besides that, the OP seems to be happy with my answer, so I'm out for now :-).

Comment: Hi Sagar, "simply create one procedure", this is what I was asking how to do. I just didn't realize it was as simple as that. Thank you.